# Channel Image regeneration error

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I'm running Channel Images 5.4.18 with EE2.9.2. I'm working on a copy on a development server doing updates.

When I go to regenerate an image size, I'm getting error messages like this, and it won't regenerate the images:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   copy(/chroot/home/account/primarydomain.com/html/secondary/system/expressionengine/cache/channel_images/imagefilename.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: local/local.php
>   Line Number: 111

I don't know how CI operates (obviously!) but I'm wondering why it would be looking in the cache for the images? This directory it's looking in doesn't exist, and it seems strange that it would look in a cache folder, which can be cleared.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you update to the question to clarify whether the directory listed in the error message actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

The cache is used to generate the images and then copy them over. Most likely your paths and urls are incorrect. I would first use something like Deeployer Helper to make sure all the paths and urls are correct. Most likely you are having issue from this.

Comment: Hmm, actually that's the first thing I did. So I moved this site over to a different server to update it. Is there any issue with clearing the cache? Or is it just that's where the work is done? Is the wrong path/url probably the upload folder for CI?

Comment: I would also look at permissions. It is one of those two things. Apache can not read/write where it needs to or the paths are wrong and it can't find stuff it needs.

Comment: I don't understand why it would use the cache to regenerate the images. It strictly says that if you don't keep the original image that you will not be able to resize them. With that said, I'm in the same boat and it just keeps failing because it can't find the cache, which isn't there because EE tells you to clear the cache when upgrading.